# How can I change the order of the items on the server and the client gets the correct order to be displayed?

Tags: java, javascript, android, ios, rest

I want to request items from a server using REST.

My client request looks like this:

```
getItems(boolean after, int offset, int size)
```

- after: if true the client wants to have items at the and of the list, if false the client wants to have items prior to the first one (in case there are any updates)
- offset: this is only used by the server if after = true, it is the last item index on the client
- size: is the max number of items the client wants to receive

This works great until there are any changes of order on the server side.

**How can I change the order of the items on the server and the client gets the correct order to be displayed?**

Should I send an ordered list of ids to the client on each request, so the client could do the sorting himself? This would increase the bytes that are transmitted.

**Edit:** The response from the server is an ordered list of items as JSON. The client will process the list in the order it receives.

The client is an App. The getItems() function is called whenever the user:

- scrolls to the end of the list,
- makes a pull to refresh gesture at the top of the list.

Comment: Can you show us what the response data looks like ? How often are you calling the getItems function on the client side ?

Comment: Could you show us the actual JSON response?

Comment: We're going to need to show the actual JSON response. Chances are, you're not sending a json array (in which case the order would be easy to get.) Also, I'm still not sure I get your question : do you want to be notified when the order changes on the server, whithout having to explicitely call "getItems" ?

Comment: @phtrivier Yes I am sending the items as a JSON Array. My question is what is a good way to handler changes of order on the client side? Should the client poll every x minutes to the get actual order or refresh the list by clearing and loading again. How would you do that?

Answer (score 0):

Never done it myself, but I suppose you could either poll regularly :

[Long-polling android technology](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20800189/long-polling-android-technology)

Or, if that's an option, push notifications when the order of elements change on the server :

http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/09/push-dont-poll-how-to-use-gcm-to-update-app-data/

Comment: I cannot use Push Notification because I cannot be sure that the each user accepts it.